# Change column type from text to integer

Tags: sql, postgresql, alter-table

I have column with type `text`
I need to change column type to integer.

I try to do it with the following script

`ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN column TYPE integer`

Obviously I get an error.

But how can I modify my script if my previous values were like `"Word1"`, `"Word2"` and now I want to keep them like `0`, `1`

If it possible I would be Ok if this script will set `0` to all rows when processing this script.

Comment: How would "Word1"/"Word2" be converted to `0` and `1`?  What is the logic?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, such things happen when you need to keep enum in database, previously we kept one of the column as a string and now we need to introduce enum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your column contains only integer values then try this way:

```
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN id  TYPE integer USING (id::integer);
```

If your column contains non-numeric values then try this way:

```
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN id  TYPE integer USING (CASE
        WHEN id~E'^\\d+$' THEN
            CAST (id AS INTEGER)
        ELSE
            0
        END);
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=cc3ba92b385267e49d886fbfc724be07)